# Convert XML to array of arrays in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am trying to convert a XML file to array of arrays. 
The second element of array will contain node paths from root and rest element contains respective data.

**XSL:**

```
<cfsavecontent variable="local.xsl">
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <!--- Get all leaf nodes XPath: *[not(*)] --->
    <xsl:key name="kNodeByPath" match="*[not(*)]" 
      use="concat(name(), '/', name(..), '/', name(../..), '/', name(../../..), 
      '/', name(../../../..), '/', name(../../../../..))"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('kNodeByPath',  
                                                              concat(name(), '/', name(..), '/', name(../..),  
                                                              '/', name(../../..), '/', name(../../../..), 
                                                              '/', name(../../../../..)))[1])]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[parent::*]" mode="path"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>

      <!--- Separate each path with comma --->
      <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '.')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</cfsavecontent>
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<table>
  <class>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <price>Test</price>
    <instruction_language>Test Data</instruction_language>
    <city>Online</city>
  </class>
  <class>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <price>Test</price>
    <instruction_language>Test Data</instruction_language>
    <city>Online</city>
  </class>
  <class>
    <id>Test Data</id>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <price>Test</price>
    <instruction_language>Test Data</instruction_language>
    <city>Online</city>
  </class>
</table>
```

**My Code:**

```
<!--- Get all distinct leaf node paths --->
<cfset local.xPath = xmlTransform(local.xml,local.xsl)>
<cfif structKeyExists(local,"xPath") AND len(local.xPath) GT 0>
    <cfset local.xPath = listToArray(local.xPath,",")>
    <cfset local.arrayData[2] = local.xPath>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(local.xPath)#" index="local.currentPath" step="1">
        <cfset local.nodePath = replaceNoCase(local.xPath[local.currentPath], ".", "/", "ALL")>

        <!--- Search node in XML --->
        <cfset local.xmlData[local.currentPath] = xmlSearch(local.xml, "//#local.nodePath#")>
    </cfloop>

    <!--- Get class node --->
    <cfset local.class = xmlSearch(local.xml, "//class")>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(local.class)#" index="local.row" step="1">
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(local.arrayData[2])#" index="local.column" step="1">
            <cfset local.arrayData[local.row + 2][local.column] = local.xmlData[local.column][local.row].xmlText>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>

<cfdump var="#local.arrayData#">
```

Actual and Expected Output:

[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you not use use xmlparse and then reference the data from there?

Comment: @andrewdixon Are you suggesting this `<cfset xml = xmlParse("E:/sample.xml")>` Then do some `XmlSearch`.

Comment: No you are will need to use cffile to read the contents of the XML file first into a variable and then you can either use the other XML functions on the resulting variable or you can reference the item nodes using the dot notation, e.g. xml.table.class.id

Comment: It can be done if I know node names. What if I don't?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you come unstuck? Show us some code.

Comment: As @AdamCameron said, we need to see what you have already tried as your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Looking at the XML, creating array of structures instead of array of arrays, seems to be more meaningful.

Comment: @andrewdixon I have updated my question and added my working code.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<cfsavecontent variable="local.xml"> 
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <table>
 <class>
  <id>Test Data</id>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
  <duration>2</duration>
  <price>Test</price>
  <instruction_language>Test Data</instruction_language>
  <city>Online</city>
   </class>
   <class>
  <id>Test Data</id>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
  <duration>2</duration>
  <price>Test</price>
  <instruction_language>Test Data</instruction_language>
  <city>Online</city>
   </class>
   <class>
  <id>Test Data</id>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <description_url>Test Data</description_url>
  <duration>2</duration>
  <price>Test</price>
  <instruction_language>Test Data</instruction_language>
  <city>Online</city>
   </class>
 </table>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset local.XmlParseData = XmlParse(trim(local.xml))>
<cfdump var="#local.XmlParseData#"><cfabort>
```